# Uploading a file, splitting then entering in a hash results in RuntimeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime-error

I have an app that uploads a text file, then saves its filename, content_type and data into its DB table.

This all works nicely, however, now I am trying to create a method where I split the file into words, split the words into letters, sort them alphabetically then join them again, all the while entering the sorted letters as a key into a hash with the words the letters represent as the values.

```
"denoops"=>[" snooped", "spooned"]
```

This works for smallish files, however when parsing a large file with 300,000 words or so, it completes enters all of the data into the hash but then errors out with:

```
expected SCALAR, SEQUENCE-START, MAPPING-START, or ALIAS
```

This is the code. NOTE UPDATE I have added serialize which saves the data as a hash to the db and changed the column type from binary to TEXT.

attachment.rb:

```
 class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :anagrams, dependent: :destroy
    attr_accessible :filename, :content_type, :data
    validates_presence_of :filename, :data
    serialize :data, Hash


    def uploaded_file=(incoming_file)
      self.filename = incoming_file.original_filename
      self.content_type = incoming_file.content_type
      results = {}

      incoming_file.read.downcase.split.each do |word|
        letters = word.split('').sort
        results[letters.join] = [[results[letters]].join(" ")] << word
        end
      self.data = results
    end
```

rails error log:

```
 Started POST "/attachments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-20 17:10:09 +0100
Processing by AttachmentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"y2S3Z6Yg9iuU74to7ZEDUedlCEsazEU26mIrsnNxgmQ=", "attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8a411497b8 @original_filename="medium_word_list.90", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment\"; filename=\"medium_word_list.90\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/1g/d9qbm7_s0_5fcljtvzysp1gc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20120820-3535-119x9hk>>, "commit"=>"upload"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11177ms

RuntimeError (expected SCALAR, SEQUENCE-START, MAPPING-START, or ALIAS):
  app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Create attachments table migration:

```
class CreateAttachments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :attachments do |t|
      t.string :filename
      t.string :content_type
      t.text :data
    end
  end
```

There's not much from Google; If anyone needs more code just say.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of refactoring and restructuring of your `uploaded_file=` method looks like:

```
def uploaded_file=(incoming_file)
  self.filename = incoming_file.original_filename
  self.content_type = incoming_file.content_type
  results = {}

  incoming_file.read.downcase.split.each do |word|
    letters = word.split('').sort
    results[
      letters
    ] = [
      [
        results[
          letters
        ]
      ].join(" ")
    ] << word 
  end

  self.data = results
end
```

The assignment to the `results` hash looks suspicious. You're assigning an array as the hash key. You then try to save that. I suspect the problem is that array as a key. Try this instead:

```
results[
  letters.join
] = [
```

Comment: Hi Tin Man, thanks for the speedy result. I've tried the solution along with some variations and it still comes back with that RunTime error, could it be something with the way the db column is configured? the field is binary but im trying to save a hash?